# Warning: include(): Failed opening 'phar://httpful.phar/Httpful/Bootstrap.php

Tags: php, rest

I use the PHP httpful to connect to a rest interface. It has been working for years but this morning, I am faced with these errors:

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'phar://httpful.phar/Httpful/Bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/myserver/public_html/lib/phar/httpful.phar on line 4

httpful.phar Content:

```
<?php
    // Phar Stub File
    Phar::mapPhar('httpful.phar');
    include('phar://httpful.phar/Httpful/Bootstrap.php');
    \Httpful\Bootstrap::pharInit();

    __HALT_COMPILER(); ?>
```

I don't understand what has changed overnight or how to fix it. Can anyone help me?